# Does javascript execution stop when an invalid line is encountered?

Tags: javascript

If the browser is executing JavaScript on a web page and it encounters invalid JavaScript
(e.g. somerandomthingy;) Does execution of JavaScript stop at that point, or do async operations continue. Also do JavaScript events still work (e.g. onclick).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, except asynchronous ones. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/R4dfJ/3/

DIY:

```
var a = 1, b, c;

setTimeout(function() {
    b = 2;
    console.log('Running', a, b, c);
}, 1000);

somerandomthingy;

c = 3;
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: somerandomthingy is not defined
>
> Running 1 2 undefined

So:

- `a` and `b` have been set
- `c` has not been set
- Timeout still occurs

As for 'does onclick still work' - well, if the handler is set in code that runs (i.e. before an error) it does; in case it is put after error code it won't bind the handler so events won't work.

Comment: So it's not supposed to affect async operations. Kewlio.

Comment: What about a more complicated setup with javascript called from multiple files?

Comment: @Kevin: See http://jsfiddle.net/TGBYV/. Basically the same thing on a per-file basis.

Comment: fascinating, thanks.  Seems to run just fine.  Would it be different in the head w/external script?  I know there's some strange order-of-operations that goes on...

Comment: @Kevin: I cannot easily test that out. I believe the order is not different though - when including scripts like `jquery.js`, `jquery.ui.js`, `jquery.ui.foo.js`, things get run successfully where each subsequent file is dependent on the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

No code is executed past the error.

```
function inAFunction(){
 alert("one");
 x = y;
 alert("two");  
}
inAFunction();
```

you will see "one" but not "two"

```
alert("one");
x = y;
alert("two");
```

you will see "one" but not "two"

```
var a = {
    b : c
}
alert("here");
```

you will see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It does somewhat depend on what you're doing. Usually things will stop executing and, if you're using a smart browser with a console, an error message will be logged (and sometimes these error messages are helpful, even, but not always).

`UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: SYNTAX ERROR, UNRECOGNIZED EXPRESSION: #`

[image]

Sometimes, however, stuff will just silently fail with no error or warning, especially if you're using jQuery or another library. I've spent hours troubleshooting why something worked fine in WebKit and Firefox but silently failed in IE, and traced the culprit to a PEBCAK bug in a jQuery .append() method that was trying to insert some invalid HTML into the DOM. It was maddening because everything else worked fine, no errors, no warnings, nothing, but in IE that one function just wouldn't "go."

Answer (score 0):

I think execution stops. If you set an alert after a line of code that breaks, you will not reach the alert, which leads me to believe that execution stops. I'm not sure if the same is true of asynch XmlHtttpRequests, though.