# Wordpress - Change Video (iframe) dimensions on the home page

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, youtube

Working on a website and having an issue with the Video output.

// The site is : http://tastethemovement.org

In the post, I embedded a Youtube Video with the width of 560px. It looks great in the post. But when that image is pulled to show on the homepage, It exceeds the dimensions allowed. I only want it to be a max of 316 pixels.

I've tried adding a width property in my css, a class to my iframe, but cannot get it to work. If I set an iframe class and only allow a width of 316px, then the video in the post also decreases.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this jQuery code in jsFiddle that expands iframe to the maximum size of the content.

In the post you add this HTML code:

```
<article>
<p><iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/...."></iframe></p>
</article>
```

In the template add the following jQuery code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function() {

var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com'], object, embed"),
$fluidEl = $("p");

$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    // jQuery .data does not work on object/embed elements
    .attr('data-aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');
});

$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
        .width(newWidth)
        .height(newWidth * $el.attr('data-aspectRatio'));

  });

}).resize();

});
});
</script>
```

I tried the code on my Wordpress site and it worked.

Comment: Works great in Chrome. Any suggestions for browser compatibility on Safari and Firefox?

Comment: I'm no expert on javascript but looking at the Chrome Developer Tool, you got quite a few Javascript errors. Try getting rid of those first. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181573/does-javascript-execution-stop-when-an-invalid-line-is-encountered

Answer (score 0):

If those images on the homepage are coming from the "set featured image" method you could do a screen grab of the video, resize that and use it as the "featured image".