# addEventListener does not work if there is another addEventListener of a non-existent html element before it

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

With @Don't Panic's suggestions, which I thank very much, I did various other tests and realized that the problem is reducible to the following:

In the same view I've a form (#form-create-comment) and a button (#btn-test) both linked with related addEventListeners included in the script tag.

```
<form id="form-create-comment" class="mb-5" action="/comment/store" method="POST">
    <!-- Submit -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Comment</button>
</form>

<button id="btn-test" class="btn btn-success">Button Test</button>


<script>
    document.getElementById('form-create-comment').addEventListener('submit', function() {
        alert('form-create-comment');
    });
    
    document.querySelector('#btn-test').addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('#btn-test');
    });
</script>
```

In this way all works but if I delete the button (#btn-test), the addEventListener of the form doesn't works unless this one in the script tag comes before the other addEventListner (#btn-test).

The same to the opposite: if I delete the form, in the scripti tag the addEventListener of the button (#btn-test) must comes before the other addEventListener (#form-create-comment).

This happened because it can't exist an addEventListener without without its reference html element or is there another explanation?

Comment: There is a lot of code here, and the problem isn't very clear.  Can you simplify the problem down to [the bare **minimum** code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) necessary to reproduce the problem?  For eg [here is a super-simplified version of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/7xjgb3c8/), where both event handlers work correctly.  What is the bare minimum of your code you need to add to that before the problem shows up?  We don't know how your various templates/layouts fit together, are you sure that all required code is in the final rendered HTML/JS sent to your browser?

Comment: "*addEventListenerY triggers an ajax call*" - isn't it `addEventListener*X*` which does that, firing `postAxios()`?  "*I specify that moving addEventListenerX happens in conjunction with the postAxios()*" - what does this mean, can you clarify?  AFAICT this is NOT the problem here, but just in case, another thing to consider - you are injecting content into the DOM after load. Event handlers that ran in the past (on page load) won't work for that new content.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896106/6089612

Comment: If you open [your browser's devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), and view the *Console* output, you will see any output and errors generated by the Javascript on your page (and doing this is really critical while developing, you are working blind otherwise).  In this case, after deleting your button, you will see:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener ...` Once you hit an unhandled error, [your JS stops running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7181573/6089612).

Comment: Thank you very much @Don't Panic, your directions were very helpful and based on these I would like to ask you what would be the best practice if the form and button-test were on two different web pages sharing the same layout.
Would it be better to link the respective addEventListener separately using inline script tags or two separate script files or a single script file by placing the addEventListener inside two IFs to avoid the browser error?

Comment: It is usually good practice to keep your JS and HTML separate, so avoid inline JS if you can.  To save HTTP requests it is common to keep all your JS in one (compressed) file.  So - as you've found! - that means you need to conditionally fire different parts depending on what page you are on.  You can do that in your JS by testing what the current page is, or maybe test if a particular class exists. [Some options described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9578348/6089612).

Comment: You might have the code separated out in big `if/else if/...` conditions, or maybe functions like `doAboutPageStuff()`, or maybe modules ...  There are no strict rules, start with something simple which works for you now, improve it over time as needed. There is a lot of wisdom archived here on SO already, even if you are not looking for code you can probably find ideas and approaches you're interested in discussed here ... search search search! :-)